# Is $X$ Hausdorff if its quotient space is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ be a set.

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a surjection and endow $Y$ with the quotient topology.

If $Y$ is Hausdorff, can I say that $X$ is also Hausdorff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is any non-Hausdorff space, $Y=\{0\}$ and $f$ is the obvious map from $X$ into $Y$ then $Y$ is Hausdorff.